# How to pass value to a imported module on a button press in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

First of all, I am a noob. On My project, I am importing a module called 'sms.js' to 'app.js' the thing I want is to pass the value of text area to a variable (var message_body) inside 'sms.js' when I press a button. here is the code that I am using.

sms.js

```
var message_body = 'Value Passing Modules';
console.log(message_body);
```

---

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sms from './Sms/Sms';
class App extends Component {
  smsHandler =() => {
    Sms();
    console.log('Sms Handler Function Testing');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <label>
            Name: 
            <input type="text" name="body" />
          </label>
        </form>
       <button onClick={this.smsHandler}>Click here</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Comment: @Svd is this answered already, or do you still need help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sms.js to receive and process some data it must export a function so that other modules can see and use it.

sms.js

```
var message_body = '';

export default function processMessage(msg) {
    message_body = msg;
    console.log(`Received message: ${msg}`);
}
```

To get the value of the input upon being clicked, an `event` object is passed to the click handler function, inputValueChange, which contains the text via `event.target.value`. Once we set this text into state, whenever we click the button, we will read the text of the input from state and send it to our SMS module.

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SMS from './Sms/Sms';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.smsHandler = this.smsHandler.bind(this);
      this.inputValueChange = this.inputValueChange.bind(this);

      this.state = {
          inputValue: ""
      };
  }

  smsHandler() {
    SMS(this.state.inputValue);
    console.log('Sms Handler Function Testing');
  }

  inputValueChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <label>
            Name: 
            <input type="text" name="body" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.inputValueChange} />
          </label>
        </form>
       <button onClick={() => { this.smsHandler(); } }>Click here</button>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It helped me to understand more about reactjs. Anyway I am getting an error 

./src/App.js
  Line 7:  'props' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Sorry i updated the code. Add `props` into `constructor(props)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed the way eventHandlers work. They are triggered on events and they receive a event object as input. In this case, you have to use the event object which comes when the change event is fired.

sms.js

```
// var message_body = 'Value Passing Modules';
// console.log(message_body);
export default function print(message) {
  console.log('received message -- ', message);
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sms from './Sms/Sms';
class App extends Component {
  smsHandler =(e) => {
    Sms(e.target.value);
    console.log('Sms Handler Function Testing');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <label>
            Name: 
            <input type="text" name="body" />
          </label>
        </form>
      <button onClick={this.smsHandler}>Click here</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please read about event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a method from `Sms.js` to take parameter and you can pass that input from `App.js`

Sms.js

```
export default function(message_body) {
  // var message_body = 'Value Passing Modules';
  console.log(message_body);
}
```

App.js

```
smsHandler =() => {
  Sms("some value");
  console.log('Sms Handler Function Testing');
}
```

You should also read about [how ES Modules work](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f) in detail.